# Sending .MOV video file as part of POST request to own server as part of a multipart/form-data request in Swift not working

Tags: swift, video, server, multipartform-data, nsdata

We are attempting to send video from iOS device or iOS simulator to our own server hosted on AWS using Swift and multipart/form-data post request.

We have the request setup in postman correctly and have tested it's success. We receive  successful 200 HTTP status codes in the postman reponse log and the video data is being transferred correctly as we are able to play the videos on device and when viewing in S3 on AWS.

However, when it comes to generation of the multipart/form-data request in Swift we have been unsuccessful so far. We initially used the Postman generated code as per the snippet below:

```
import Foundation
#if canImport(FoundationNetworking)
import FoundationNetworking
#endif

var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)

let parameters = [
        [
                "key": "video",
                "src": "device_file_url",
                "type": "file"
        ]] as [[String : Any]]

let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
var body = ""
var error: Error? = nil
for param in parameters {
        if param["disabled"] == nil {
                let paramName = param["key"]!
                body += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
                body += "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(paramName)\""
                if param["contentType"] != nil {
                        body += "\r\nContent-Type: \(param["contentType"] as! String)"
                }
                let paramType = param["type"] as! String
                if paramType == "text" {
                        let paramValue = param["value"] as! String
                        body += "\r\n\r\n\(paramValue)\r\n"
                } else {
                        let paramSrc = param["src"] as! String
                        let fileData = try NSData(contentsOfFile:paramSrc, options:[]) as Data
                        let fileContent = String(data: fileData, encoding: .utf8)!
                        body += "; filename=\"\(paramSrc)\"\r\n"
                          + "Content-Type: \"content-type header\"\r\n\r\n\(fileContent)\r\n"
                }
        }
}
body += "--\(boundary)--\r\n";
let postData = body.data(using: .utf8)

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://url_to_server/")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
request.addValue("token xxxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = postData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in 
        guard let data = data else {
                print(String(describing: error))
                semaphore.signal()
                return
        }
        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        semaphore.signal()
}

task.resume()
semaphore.wait()
```

This line seems to convert the file to a byte array Per this image [Video data in Bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giJOn.png) :

```
let fileData = try NSData(contentsOfFile:paramSrc, options:[]) as Data
```

And the following line then errors out (b/c of the failed unwrapping due to nil value being hit from the line above):

```
let fileContent = String(data: fileData, encoding: .utf8)!
```

Therefore we assumed the issue is likely due to the conversion of the .MOV / video file to a Data object / string before being passed into the body of the request.

---

We then used an alternative decoding strategy for the fileContent line as per this:

```
let fileContent = String(decoding: fileData, as: UTF8.self)
```

This was successfull in terms of receving a successful HTTP response code of 200 and the videoUrl on the server side recognising that an object has been sent. However when printing the fileContent string, it is a a long string of random characters as per this image:
[Swift console log of fileContent string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRC3v.png)

And when viewing the endpoint in AWS S3 the asset shows no video with supported format and mime type is found (all browsers have the same response) [Error of video format screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EtQW.png) suggesting that the conversion of the video to data is incorrect/corrupted and therefore not working.

---

The questions I have are:

1. What is the most effcient way to send video data from iOS device or simulator as part of a HTTP request to a server? Multipart/form-data?
   --- 1.2) If Multipart/form-data is the best method, what is correct way to convert video's to data and send as part of a post request?
2. Are there any other methods that are advantageous in sending this sort of data?

I would expect there to be extensive documentation on this sort of topic given a large amount of applications send video from device to server but I haven't come across a solution that works just yet.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Ask one question at a time unless you want to get your topic closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Intro:

I wouldn't transform it into String...
Thinking that every data can be a valid UTF8 string, that's a big mistake... But a valid UTF8 string into `Data`, that works every time.

```
let stringImage = String(data: anyUIImage.pngData()!, encoding: .utf8)
```

Should give normally `nil` value...

### In use:

Instead, make `body` a `Data`, not a `String`, since in the end, `httpBody` is a `Data`.

```
var body = Data()
```

When you want to append a `String`:

```
body += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
```

=>

```
body += Data("--\(boundary)\r\n".utf8)
```

If you have a `Data` parameter, append it directly.

Then, for your video content;

```
let paramSrc = param["src"] as! String
let fileData = try NSData(contentsOfFile:paramSrc, options:[]) as Data
let fileContent = String(data: fileData, encoding: .utf8)!
body += "; filename=\"\(paramSrc)\"\r\n"
        + "Content-Type: \"content-type header\"\r\n\r\n\(fileContent)\r\n"
```

Should be:

```
if let source = param["src"] as? String, let fileContent = try? Data(contentsOf: source) {
    body += Data("; filename=\"\(paramSrc)\"\r\n".utf8)
    body += Data("Content-Type: \"content-type header\"\r\n".utf8)
    //Now, appending the data
    body += Data("\r\n".utf8)
    body += fileContent
    body += Data("\r\n".utf8)
}
```

And in the end:

```
request.httpBody = body
```

Comment: Exceptionally gratefull for the explanation and the speed you answered. It worked well and now we have video data being transferred seamlessly!